# How to calculate hourly, daily, monthly and yearly average between two dates?

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing an application in PHP. I use MySql database for that. I want to calculate **Hourly**, **Daily**, **Monthly** and **Yearly** average **between two dates**.

My query for hourly average is

```
SELECT avg(value) 
FROM table_name  
WHERE (added_date BETWEEN '2014-01-29 00:00:00' AND '2014-01-31 00:00:00') 
GROUP BY DATE(added_date), HOUR(added_date)  
ORDER BY added_date ASC
```

Now i want to do the same query for calculate daily, monthly and yearly average.
Please suggest solution. Thanks

Comment: Oh, consider providing proper DDLs (and/or am sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just mean something like these?

Hourly average

```
SELECT DATE(added_date), HOUR(added_date) , avg(value) 
FROM table_name  
WHERE (added_date BETWEEN '2013-01-29 00:00:00' AND '2014-01-31 00:00:00') 
GROUP BY DATE(added_date), HOUR(added_date)  
ORDER BY added_date ASC
```

Daily average

```
SELECT DATE(added_date) , avg(value) 
FROM table_name  
WHERE (added_date BETWEEN '2013-01-29 00:00:00' AND '2014-01-31 00:00:00') 
GROUP BY DATE(added_date)
ORDER BY added_date ASC
```

Monthly average

```
SELECT YEAR(added_date), MONTH(added_date), avg(value) 
FROM table_name  
WHERE (added_date BETWEEN '2013-01-29 00:00:00' AND '2014-01-31 00:00:00') 
GROUP BY YEAR(added_date), MONTH(added_date)
ORDER BY added_date ASC
```

Yearly average

```
SELECT YEAR(added_date), avg(value) 
FROM table_name  
WHERE (added_date BETWEEN '2013-01-29 00:00:00' AND '2014-01-31 00:00:00') 
GROUP BY YEAR(added_date)  
ORDER BY added_date ASC
```